# SQL JOIN To Find Records That Don't Have a Matching Record With a Specific Value

Tags: sql, mysql, join, subquery

I'm trying to speed up some code that I wrote years ago for my employer's purchase authorization app.  Basically I have a SLOW subquery that I'd like to replace with a JOIN (if it's faster).

When the director logs into the application he sees a list of purchase requests he has yet to authorize or deny. That list is generated with the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM SA_ORDER WHERE ORDER_ID NOT IN
    (SELECT ORDER_ID FROM SA_SIGNATURES WHERE TYPE = 'administrative director');
```

There are only about 900 records in sa_order and 1800 records in sa_signature and this query still takes about 5 seconds to execute. I've tried using a LEFT JOIN to retrieve records I need, but I've only been able to get sa_order records with NO matching records in sa_signature, and I need sa_order records with "no matching records with a type of 'administrative director'".  Your help is greatly appreciated!

The schema for the two tables is as follows:

The tables involved have the following layout:

```
CREATE TABLE sa_order
(
    `order_id`        BIGINT       PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `order_number`    BIGINT       NOT NULL,
    `submit_date`     DATE         NOT NULL,
    `vendor_id`       BIGINT       NOT NULL,
    `DENIED`          BOOLEAN      NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE,
    `MEMO`            MEDIUMTEXT,
    `year_id`         BIGINT       NOT NULL,
    `advisor`         VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `deleted`         BOOLEAN      NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE
);

CREATE TABLE sa_signature
(
    `signature_id`        BIGINT          PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `order_id`            BIGINT          NOT NULL,
    `signature`           VARCHAR(255)    NOT NULL,
    `proxy`               BOOLEAN         NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE,
    `timestamp`           TIMESTAMP       NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
    `username`            VARCHAR(255)    NOT NULL,
    `type`                VARCHAR(255)    NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: Though Radu's suggestion of using NOT EXISTS instead of NOT IN sped the query up somewhat, Quassnoi's answer of adding indexes on type and order_id fields made the query run like lightning.  Thanks to everyone for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an index on `sa_signatures (type, order_id)`.

This is not necessary to convert the query into a `LEFT JOIN` unless `sa_signatures` allows nulls in `order_id`. With the index, the `NOT IN` will perform as well. However, just in case you're curious:

```
SELECT  o.*
FROM    sa_order o
LEFT JOIN
        sa_signatures s
ON      s.order_id = o.order_id
        AND s.type = 'administrative director'
WHERE   s.type IS NULL
```

You should pick a `NOT NULL` column from `sa_signatures` for the `WHERE` clause to perform well.

Comment: Excellent! After creating those indexes and running an optimize on my table the query execution time went from 5 seconds to .04.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could replace the [NOT] IN operator with EXISTS for faster performance.

So you'll have:

```
SELECT * FROM SA_ORDER WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT ORDER_ID FROM SA_SIGNATURES
     WHERE TYPE = 'administrative director'
       AND ORDER_ID = SA_ORDER.ORDER_ID);
```

Reason : "When using “NOT IN”, the query performs nested full table scans, whereas for “NOT EXISTS”, query can use an index within the sub-query."

Source  : http://decipherinfosys.wordpress.com/2007/01/21/32/

Comment: this is only the case if `ORDER_ID` allows nulls. The link you provided is `Oracle` specific, the `MySQL`'s optimizer differs much from the `Oracle`'s one. `FULLSCAN` here is only because `Oracle` won't index `NULL` columns, unlike `MySQL`.

Answer (score 0):

This following query should work, however I suspect your real issue is you don't have the proper indices in place. You should have an index on the SA_SGINATURES table on the ORDER_ID column.

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
SA_ORDER 
LEFT JOIN
SA_SIGNATURES
ON
SA_ORDER.ORDER_ID = SA_SIGNATURES.ORDER_ID AND
TYPE = 'administrative director'
WHERE 
SA_SIGNATURES.ORDER_ID IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

select * from sa_order as o inner join sa_signature as s on o.orderid = sa.orderid and sa.type = 'administrative director'

also, you can create a non clustered index on type in sa_signature table

even better - have a master table for types with typeid and typename, and then instead of saving type as text in your sa_signature table, simply save type as integer. thats because computing on integers is way faster than computing on text