# Merge Function in R

Tags: r, merge

I am using merge() function in R. I want to merge two dataframes. However, I am interested in the observations that don't merge.  Is there a way to produce output that shows the observations that did not successfully merge?

Example: DataframeA=1138888 obs
         DataframeB=1010651 obs
I want to see which obs were not included in DataframeB that were included in DataFrameA.

I have read through the merge() documentation and saw all.x, all.y commands.  However, I really want a new dataframe that represents those observations that would NOT merge.

Thank you an advance for any help.

Comment: probably using `match()` would help.  Can you post a reproducible example?

Comment: Yes the match() function worked. Thank you! So simple. This is what happens after working on an analysis all day.  Much appreciated!

Comment: You could also try `anti_join` from the **dplyr** package.

Answer (score 1):

Dont know how computationally effectiv the following solution is but it works
with `subset()`

```
df.a<-data.frame(key=sample(1:100,50),"a")
df.b<-data.frame(key=sample(1:100,50),"b")
db.bNOTa<-subset(df.b,!(df.b$key %in% df.a$key))
```

Edit:
Another solution using `match` would be:

```
db.bNOTa<-merge(df.b,df.a,all.x=TRUE)
db.bNOTa<-subset(db.bNOTa,!is.na(db.bNOTa[,3]))
```

In MySQL this would be a Left Join like Pointed out here:
[SQL JOIN To Find Records That Don't Have a Matching Record With a Specific Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853203/sql-join-to-find-records-that-dont-have-a-matching-record-with-a-specific-value?answertab=active#tab-top)